# Android timer/timertask causing my app to crash?

Tags: java, android, timer

Just testing out a simple block of code in my mainActivity's onCreate:

```
Timer timer2 = new Timer(); 
        TimerTask testing = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() { 
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };
        timer2.schedule(testing, 1000);
```

I get the "force close" error though.

What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright for anyone else who runs into this, I fixed the problem by using a Handler and Runnable to do the Toast, which seems to be needed for UI interaction:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    Timer timer2 = new Timer(); 
    TimerTask testing = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() { 
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });


        }
    };
    timer2.schedule(testing, 1000);
```

I still don't understand why this is necessary though, perhaps someone could explain? But hey at least this code works lol.

Comment: GUI programs usually have a single thread that is responsible for refreshing and drawing the UI. Other threads trying to update the UI are stepping on this UI thread's toes and causes it to crash. Instead you need to pass messages to the UI thread which is what the handler does.

Answer (score 3):

**Timer(Tasks) are bad! Do it the Android way: Use a Handler.**

As you can see in the code snippet, it’s pretty easy to go that way too:

First we need a Handler that starts the Runnable after 100ms

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
```

And we also need the Runnable for the Handler

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      /* do what you need to do */
      foobar();
      /* and here comes the "trick" */
      handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
   }
};
```

So the “trick” is to tell the handler at the end to start the Runnable again. This way the runnable is started every 100ms, like a scheduleAtFixedRate() TimerTask! If you want it to stop, you can just call **handler.removeCallback(runnable)** and it won’t start again, until you tell it to

Comment: This worked perfectly for my interrupt requirements, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This exact issue is discussed in this article:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Answer (score 1):

The app crashes because you are attempting to access elements of the UI thread (a toast) from a different thread (the timer thread). You cannot do this!

You can get round it by either:

Sending a handler message from the timer thread to the UI thread, and then showing the toast in the UI handler function.

OR

In the timer code run use 'runOnUiThread':

```
@Override

public void run() 

{

    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            // Access/update UI here

            Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@YoungMoney

It works but only the first time... Did you make it display the Toast message every second??

Mine only worked once...

===

Edit:
Just realised your last line of code is missing the last value which is how often to repeat.

For anyone else concerned, change this:

```
timer2.schedule(testing, 1000);
```

to this:

```
timer2.schedule(testing, 1000, 2000);
```

If you want to start the timer in 1 second, and update every 2 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something

    }
};

Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(task, 2000);
```

Comment: This doesnt explain the reason for the crash, and TimerTask's should be replaced with Handlers.